# Using PHP mail - setting correct MIME type

Tags: php, html, email, header, mime

I've got a problem with a PHP script which sends an email confirmation. When receiving the email in Thunderbird, the header comes through with the \r\n present and with the MIME type also containing the Content-type information. Hence the email renders as plain text, rather than HTML.

If I comment out the MIME type as below, the email renders correctly. Firstly, is there a significant problem doing this, and secondly, what might be causing this?

```
if($apptpro_config->html_email == "Yes"){
        //$headers .= 'MIME-Version:1.0\r\n';
        $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';
    }   



    return(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644081/what-is-the-format-for-e-mail-headers-that-display-a-name-rather-than-the-e-mail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you enclose \r\n in double quotes (not single quotes!) so that PHP can translate that into the correct linefeed code

`$header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";`

Comment: I've done this (albeit with the MIME and Content-Type on separate lines, but when the email comes through I get Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 in the top of the email body. The MIME type is set correctly in the header.

Comment: <?php  
mail('recipient@some.net', 'Subject',  
    'Your message here',  
    "To: The Receiver <recipient@some.net>\n" .  
    "From: The Sender <sender@some.net>\n" .  
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .  
    "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1");  
?>

Comment: Very systematic tutorial about advance PHP mail can be found at http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/advanced-email-php

Comment: I looked at the same sitepoint article and got: $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"; - as you had. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the specific answer you are looking for, but have you tried Zend Mail?

It streamlines setting up HTML emails and you can configure it to send a plain text version as well, if HTML is disabled on the clients end.

Check it out: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html-mails.html

Comment: This is actually within Joomla so it's using mail within Joomla - still php mail but within their framework so not worth adding something else.

Comment: Why do people down-vote comments that are 5 years old?! Back then ZF was a good alternative. 5 years on, not so much.