# Send an email after register

Tags: php, email

I have a member system and have created a function where you need to active your account by email.

It succesfully sends emails, but the problem is you see the email in 'From' in your inbox.

I want to sent the email by `no-reply@mysite.com` from:`SITE NAME` subject:`SUBJECT`
I can't do both `sent` and `from`

I got this now:

```
public function sendActivation($to, $subject, $body) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: SITE NAAM', 'From: EMAIL@site.com');
}
```

An email is sent after registration of an account with success:

```
User::sendActivation(Input::get('email'), 'Email verification', 'okeoke');
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644081/what-is-the-format-for-e-mail-headers-that-display-a-name-rather-than-the-e-mail

Comment: You're overwriting your `From:` try `mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: SITE NAAM <EMAIL@site.com>');`

Comment: Not a problem. @Benny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify both sender and sender's name, replace the headers with this:

```
'From: SITE NAAM <no-reply@mysite.com>'
```