# $email_headers .= 'From:' Returns incorrect format

Tags: php

Normal emails that come in any email client look like this:
`John <john@abc.com>`

All my test messages from the script are arriving like this:
`"John noreply"@abc.com`

What I want is this:
`John <noreply@abc.com>` (preferable format)

or I'd even be okay with  `"John" noreply@abc.com`

No Quotations. At least no quotation before the @ symbol.
Example from above: ...noreply"@abc.com

Tried solutions "User Mario" sent me at my original question:
["FROM" using default CPANEL address in "mail.php"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055133/from-using-default-cpanel-address-in-mail-php?noredirect=1#comment102509049_58055133)

```
#### My changed php code ####

$email_headers .= 'From:' . $first_name . ' ' . 'noreply@abc.com' . "\r\n";
        $email_headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $email . "\r\n";
```

I can't figure out why the quote appear before the @ symbol. What am I missing? Example from above: ...noreply"@abc.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the format for e-mail headers that display a name rather than the e-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644081/what-is-the-format-for-e-mail-headers-that-display-a-name-rather-than-the-e-mail)

Comment: _"I can't figure out why the parenthesis appear before the @ symbol"_ - You mean the quote? Well, in the above posted code for `From` wouldn't give you a quote before the @ symbol. If you get that, it must come from somewhere else.  Please share the code you have before and after the posted code. You should also wrap the email in `<noreply@abc.com>`.

Comment: yes, I meant quote. I'll edit.

Comment: I assume that quote is your email client trying to correct the missing quotes/brackets. Your `From` becomes `John noreply@abc.com` and due to the missing `<` and `>` brackets it assumes the name is "John noreply".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use '<' and '>' symbol surrounding the real email address then prefixed with the display name of the sender.

```
#### My changed php code ####

$email_headers .= 'From: ' . $first_name . " <noreply@abc.com>\r\n";
$email_headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $email . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Although this is true, it's not really what question seem to be about though. They seem to get a strange `"`-character before the `@`-symbol in their email address.

Comment: Thank you Josh-WBS. I've literally tried the <> symbols everywhere but exactly where I needed them. Thank you!